# Proper usage of logarithmic notations in scientific papers

Tags: scientific-notation, natural-logarithm

Recently I was told that scientific papers in English use - `log_e` while French papers use - `ln` to denote natural logarithms.

The two notations mean the same but I was told that using the notation `ln` for natural logarithms in English scientific papers is wrong. But I have always been using `log` for log-base-10 and `ln` for natural logarithms. (At least this was what I was taught in school)

Do such notations vary from language to language?

I am referring to the publications specific to IEEE, Elsevier etc. related to the Electrical and Electronics field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding **natural logarithm:**
To my experience everyone knows ln(x) = log<sub>*e*</sub>(x) 
Usage of either is more related to the field of science, where engineers and physicists typically use log<sub>*e*</sub>(x) and mathematicians use ln(x), but I've never seen an actual convention from **IEEE** on this.
I'd recommend you using the one you are familiar with, so you are consistent throughout your own work (That is the most important).

Regarding **base-10-logarithm:**
Using log(x) for base-10-logarithm is often seen in engineering. However, I must advise against that because mathematicians use log(x) for natural logarithm, making both usecases ambiguous.
Try to put in log(x) to any calculator and it will assume natural logarithm.
I have seen a ton of errors and misunderstandings arrise from this.
Some engineers argues that base-10-logarithm is implied since engineers only work in base-10, however this is not true - "Trust me. I'm an Engineer"

Always write log<sub>base</sub>(x) or ln(x) to be explicit about the base used.

Comment: [`log` may even mean log base 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases). IMHO the ISO notation is clearer

Comment: @Martin This is exactly what I've been looking for. Well-explained and precise. Thanks mate!